# What determines file upload speed in shiny server?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I've built a shiny app that requires user to upload data. I have a file of around 11.2MB and its upload is almost instantaneous locally. But when I deploy the app on an instance of shiny server on our company server, it takes around 5-10secs to upload the same file. And it gets worse if the file uploaded is 100MB.

Is there a setting in shiny-server (probably in shiny-server.conf) to determine file upload speed? Or is this behavior caused by other factors?

Comment: A couple of possible candidates: i) internet speed between user and server, ii) is your app doing anything to the data while/after reading it in? (if so, that could require memory or compute resources that are plentiful on your laptop but not so on the server/pod/node on which your app runs). I'm guessing a little here and am interested what others say.

Comment: "Is your app doing anything to the data while/after reading it in?" No. After upload the user has to make column selections and nothing is done until clicking of "Calculate" button. 
My internet upload speed is 3Mbps so that might be the cause. 
Let's see what others have to say.